# My favorite privacy settings

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for general feedback on this module.  Here is what it handles on the page:

[image: Privacy Settings dialog, showing 'normal' and 'secretive' radiobuttons, a 'cancel' and a 'save' button]

This is a private "class" meaning none of its properties are available outside of it.

`init` is run at run-time.  `pre` sets up parameters to be sent to the server via ajax and `post` receives the ajax response.

I can post the code for Class.create if needed, but I wanted to focus on the class itself.

```
$A.Class.create('private', {
    Name: 'Settings',
    E: {
        save_button:  '#save_button',
        cancel_button:  '#cancel_button',
        se_form: '#se_form'
    },
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        $(this.E.save_button).on("click", function () {
            $A.Packet.push({model: self.Name});
        });
        $(this.E.cancel_button).on("click", function () {
            Page.flip('fave');
        });
    },
    pre: function (packet) {
        packet.h_token = Storage.getRemembered();
        packet.privacy = this.getSaved();
        packet.state = true;
        return packet;
    },
    post: function (packet) {
        Page.flip('fave_custom');
        return packet;
    },
    getSaved: function () {
        var form_elements = this.E.se_form.elements,
            send_value = '',
            iterator;
        for (iterator = 0; iterator < form_elements.length; iterator++) {
            if (form_elements[iterator].checked) {
                send_value = form_elements[iterator].value;
            }
        }
        return send_value;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd add a bit more margin between the radiobutton/setting name and its description. That said, "general feedback" is implied by merely posting here, and "JavaScript" is covered with the [tag:javascript] tag - I've edited the title to make it a bit more descriptive (and punny!), feel free to [edit] it again to improve it.

Comment: it has been done ... in the CSS ...  hey, this is a JS question.

Comment: This question has been [mentioned on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6778/9357).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main improvement with this code would be your handling of jQuery elements.  You should save them in the object literal like you did with plain elements.

Secondly, you can shorten up your code, using jQuery to pull the radio button value.

Your code might be a bit faster, as it works at a lower abstraction level, but if you do choose to use it, it might be better to abstract it out into a DOM function.

Below is the modified code.

```
$A.Class.create('private', {
    Name: 'Settings',
    J: {
        save_button:          $('#save_button'),
        cancel_button:        $('#cancel_button')
    },
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.J.save_button.on("click", function () {
            $A.Packet.push({model: self.Name});
        });
        this.J.cancel_button.on("click", function () {
            Page.flip('fave');
        });
    },
    pre: function (packet) {
        packet.h_token = Storage.getRemembered();
        packet.privacy = this.getSaved();
        packet.state = true;
        return packet;
    },
    post: function (packet) {
        Page.flip('fave_custom');
        return packet;
    },
    getSaved: function () {
        return $('input[name=privacy]:checked', '#se_form').val(); 
    }
});

/* Put in a DOM abstraction library

            var form_elements = this.E.se_form.elements,
                send_value = '',
                iterator;
            for (iterator = 0; iterator < form_elements.length; iterator++) {
                if (form_elements[iterator].checked) {
                    send_value = form_elements[iterator].value;
                }
            }
            return send_value;
        }
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

For one, you're mixing `"` and `'` in the same code. Try using just one of them (I prefer the `'`).

Probably personal preference, but a `var` for all variables is hard to read. You have to keep in mind the commas and you can't simply move the variables around without redefining the `var`.

Unless `E` is a construct of your framework, it's hard to read. What in the world is `E`. If it was morning and I'm hungry, I'd think of `E` as eggs. Where are my eggs??? :D Also, it would be great if you didn't name things relative to something else. For instance, `pre` and `post`... of what? Name your entities properly and precisely. That way, you leave no one guessing. Programming is for humans to read.

One nice thing about JS is dynamicity. One terrible thing about JS is also dynamicity. In this case, `this.E.se_form` is a string. When does it become an object with an `element` property? It's not explicitly defined anywhere at all. Having too many implicit operations can cost you time down the road. Best if you make it explicit, like defining `se_form` as an object, or adding a comment when it became an object.

Comment: I use E to hold DOM elements.  I've seen `el` used in many other cases, so I think in the context of web programming,  if you had to pick what E stands for, I would go with elements.